# is there a free *native* application for testing HDCP support?

Tags: display

I'm currently troubleshooting/[trying to work out some issues with HDCP support](https://superuser.com/questions/1775708/why-isnt-the-netflix-app-doing-uhd-output-on-my-pc/1775709#1775709). At the moment my 'best' option for working out HDCP *versions* is a webapp - which is a little janky since I need to click through each HDCP version and check. I *will* be getting a device that lets me 'fake' HDCP settings so I can check. This is only really an issue on windows, and I'd like a more elegant way to check and document these things

I feel like *if* a webapp can check these things, there should be a native tool that should do this, I don't want to step through each version. I need to know what I support *now*

My minimum requirements are

- Needs to run on windows 10 or 11
- Needs to tell me if HDCP 2.2 is supported, since that seems to be the sticking point
- Not GPU vendor specific (The NVIDIA driver method for example is both practically useless since I need a specific version, and I can't use it on say the AMD NUC I use as a HTPC)

Nice to have features

- More fully featured monitor information so I don't need to cross check with system settings. Something like CPU-Z or GPU-Z for monitors would be excellent
- what's the highest supported HDCP version
- Tells me *why* its not supported. I run a mix of monitors and my best case scenario for now is having 3 different displays with 3 different levels of HDCP support and knowing that monitor 2 is supporting only 1.0 and monitor 3 does not support HDCP at all would be nice
- supports multiple monitors. I can disable individual monitors if REALLY needed though.
- Portable

Can I have a pony?

- Netflix is the 'only' application I really have issues with at the moment, and is the only streaming application I have a subscription for. I feel like an application you can run and tell you what you need to do higher resolutions (UHD) on various 'native' streaming applications is what's 'really' needed.

Comment: Quick side note - in case someone comes across the cyberlink blueray and 3d advisor - its woefully out of date and looks like a 'yes/no' rather than a "this is why it isn't working"